# Out of memory exception after selecting images

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to show a list of selected images by user:

```
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        var fileName = e.OriginalFileName;
        var photoStream = e.ChosenPhoto;
    }
}
```

and

```
<Image Source="{Binding PhotoStream}" Width="200" Height="200"/>
```

the problem is after selecting 4 or 5 images, app hits memory limit and exits. I just want to show thumbnails of those selected images, like PhotoHub, how can I do that without consuming a lot of memory? thanks

Comment: Your question is very broad. There could be a few ways to consume less memory. Rather post the code where you are getting the exception, or a sample application replicating the error

Comment: Are you really using Windows Phone 7? If so why did you tag it 8? Please do not abuse the windows phone tags

Comment: @AMR updated. (can't someone make app for both?!)

Comment: Windows Phone 7 is deprecated. You can only deploy 7.8 and 8 now to the market

Comment: @Downvoters, I really don't understand why? if something is wrong clarify, just downvoting doesn't help a lot :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there are several ways to solve it, and as you mention you will probably need a thumbnail. Here are some methods I can think of right now which might solve your memory problem:

**Method 1:**

First using the `MediaLibrary` to find the same image, where you will get a stream to a thumbnail version, like this:

```
void task_Completed(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.TaskResult.OK)
    {
        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
        Picture pic = library.Pictures.Where(p => e.OriginalFileName.EndsWith("\\" + p.Album.Name + "\\" + p.Name)).FirstOrDefault();
        Stream thumbnailStream = pic.GetThumbnail(); // Stream to a thumbnail
    }
}
```

For this to work you will also need to enabled the capability `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO` in the `WMAppManifest.xml` or you wont get any results.

**Method 2:**

The second option would be to use for example the [WriteableBitmapEx library](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) to create a thumbnail yourself, something along the lines of:

```
void task_Completed(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.TaskResult.OK)
    {
        BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
        source.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(source);
        WriteableBitmap thumbnail = bitmap.Resize(100, 100, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear); // Creates a 100x100 thumbnail
    }
}
```

**Other methods:**

Another solution might be using the [Nokia Imaging SDK](http://developer.nokia.com/lumia/nokia-apis/imaging), which according to the documentation supports partial JPEG decoding (I haven't used this SDK myself so can't give you any example code right now though):

> Using RAJPEG technology, access image data without decoding a whole
>   JPEG image for blazingly fast previews, application of effects,
>   rotation, and cropping of high resolution images.